# Formset initial choice field

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form (working correctly) which I want to pass to a Formset, but the tuples Im passing for the ChoiceFields are not rendered or have a error:

This is the original form:

```
class PO_Form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, baseItem_choices, color_choices, material_choices, sizeGroup_choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PO_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['base_item'].choices = baseItem_choices
        self.fields['color_or_print'].choices = color_choices
        self.fields['material'].choices = material_choices
        self.fields['size_group'].choices = sizeGroup_choices

    base_item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
    color_or_print = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
    material = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
    size_group = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
```

this form ChoiceFields are populated from various lists of touples which I create in a view:

```
form = PO_Form(baseItem_choices, color_choices, material_choices, sizeGroup_choices)
```

How I make this work in a formset? I tried two approaches:
1:

```
PO_FormSet = formset_factory(PO_Form(baseItem_choices, color_choices, material_choices, sizeGroup_choices), extra=2)
```

I get this Error:

> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/carlospceballos/Dropbox
>   (Personal)/django/projectos/WholeSale/ShowRoom/views.py" in
>   PO_formset_populate
>     115.     PO_FormSet = formset_factory(PO_Form(baseItem_choices, color_choices, material_choices, sizeGroup_choices), extra=2)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in
>   formset_factory
>     449.     return type(form.**name** + str('FormSet'), (formset,), attrs)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /showroom/po_populate/3/ Exception
>   Value: 'PO_Form' object has no attribute '**name**'

2: I tried setting the initial values in the view:

```
PO_FormSet = formset_factory(PO_Form(), extra=2)
formset = PO_FormSet(initial=[
    {   'base_item': baseItem_choices,
        'color_or_print': color_choices,
        'material': material_choices,
        'size_group': sizeGroup_choices, }
])
```

If I don't modified PO_Form an error arises saying the the form takes 5 arguments and Im only passing 1. If I modify the form (strip away the **init**) I get no error but the Choice Fields are empty... What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the instance of the form instead of the form class to the `formset_factory` method. You can set the choices after instantiating the formset.

forms.py:

```
class PO_Form(forms.Form):
    base_item = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
    color_or_print = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
    material = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
    size_group = forms.ChoiceField(choices=(), required=True)
```

views.py:

```
PO_FormSet = formset_factory(PO_Form)

formset = PO_FormSet()

for form in formset.forms:
    form.fields['base_item'].choices = baseItem_choices
    form.fields['color_or_print'].choices = color_choices
    form.fields['material'].choices = material_choices
    form.fields['size_group'].choices = sizeGroup_choices
```