# Django: dynamic choice field for formsets

Tags: django, django-forms, formset, dynamic-forms

So I have a form

```
class DownloadForm(forms.Form):

    title = forms.CharField()
    device_family = forms.ChoiceField(label="Device Family",
                                          widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                     'data-toggle': 'select'}),
                                          choices=LOG_ENTRY_TYPES, required=True
                                      )
```

and in view.py I do

```
LOG_ENTRY_TYPES = (
            ('', 'All'),
            ('auth', 'Auth'),
            ('error', 'Error'),
            ('info', 'Info'),
            ('proxy', 'Proxy'),
        )
DownloadFormSet = formset_factory(DownloadForm)
        formsets = DownloadFormSet(initial=[
            {'title': 'Django is now open source', 'device_family': LOG_ENTRY_TYPES},
            {'title': 'Django source 2', 'device_family': LOG_ENTRY_TYPES},
            {'title': 'Django source 3', 'device_family': LOG_ENTRY_TYPES}
        ])
```

This creates the `device_family` field but the `LOG_ENTRY_TYPES` choices are not generated. So how can I pass the `LOG_ENTRY_TYPES` choices to the `device_family` choices field so that the drop down shows the choices.

Comment: Did you try to initialize forms in formsets like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41229753/formset-initial-choice-field ?
form.fields['device_family'].choices = device_family_choices 
? Maybe this method will work out :)